# Archiving Theory

Tags: mysql, sql, database, archiving

I am about to set up a new database that will need to include archiving of records that are still accessible.  Records are all associated with certain projects and when the project is archived, I want the records to stay the same, a snapshot. (e.g. If a contact is associated with an archived project, and they move a year later, I want it to still pull the old address.)  The archived records do not need to be updated, but they do need to be accessible.

I have an idea of how to go about this, but I am not sure if this is the best approach:  Have a duplicate of each table that would "archive" everything, and then when putting an item in archive, all the FK/PK relationships would be updated, though that seems like a cumbersome process.

Another idea I had was each item (i.e. contact) would be assigned a PK and then there would be  a secondary key for each item which would then be associated with each project.  The main problem with this is it seems difficult if a contact updates on a live project, a lot of updates would be required.

Please let me know if you have any questions.

Thank you for the help.

Comment: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/archive-storage-engine.html And this might be more appropriate on SeverFault. See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/65093/best-way-to-archive-live-mysql-database

Comment: You could also look into partitioning of the tables, that would be transparent to your application. But that question belongs on serverfault as well.

Answer (score 0):

Hm... The only time I came accross with something like this, there was the idea to solve it in the application layer, and not on the db.

For instance, for ruby, you may use vestal_versions or paper-trail.

Paper-trail, for instance, stores the versions of all objects as serialized objects on one single table, and works with deltas.

Answer (score 0):

What you are looking for is to include temporal data along side your domain data. This sort of a thing isn't a trivial task to undertake and is often the cause of great complication in applications that need to support it.

There are a number of ways to go about doing this, each with their pros and cons, and the way you choose will depend on *what* you need to do with the temporal element of your data. Some of these include:

1. Audit trail

   - You track the changes made to a record over time and the primary record reflects it's current state
   - Reduces data duplication to a minimum
   - Likely doesn't fit the "snapshot" model you are looking for easily
2. Most Current

   - You have a record for each "version" of an entity with a timestamp of when it was created
   - Makes it easy to jump back to a point in time
   - Makes it easy to "fork" an entity
   - Has the most data duplication

Martin Fowler has written some articles relating to designing models that deal with temporal data, so I would start there for a good, solid grounding in the topic.